# Calculate raycast with specific PxRigidStatic object

Tags: collision-detection, physx

I've a `PxRigidStatic` object loaded in PhysX.

I want to calculate the intersection point between this object and a ray.

In the documentation I've found the [QxScene::raycast](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/SceneQueries.html#basic-queries) method but it works with every object loaded into the scene, so it hit also other objects (I want to calculate the height of a mesh representing a terrain but when I execute the raycast I obtain intersection with players that are in the same position).

Is it possible to set the query only for a specific object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use filterFlag to filter out all players (I suppose they are dynamic) or filterData (in a mask manner).